# Make TextView in layout scrollable

Tags: android, textview

i think it's mainstream when i ask about this... but i really stuck i have tried to change layout in xml to make the textview scrollable or layout scrollable because i insert many words in that textView then it overlapped the radiobutton
here is the xml file... i wish i could make it not radiobutton again.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtUser" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="user :" />



        <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtSoalCount" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:textSize="32sp"
      android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/txtSoalCount"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="timer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtScore"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="Score" />



       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/mainContent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_below="@id/timer"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:weightSum="2" >



       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
                   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainContent">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txtSoal"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Dummy Tect" />
           </ScrollView>

       </LinearLayout> 


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
           <RadioGroup
               android:id="@+id/rgAnswer"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical" >
               <RadioButton
                   android:id="@+id/rb_A"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
               android:text="A." /> 
               <RadioButton
                   android:id="@+id/rb_B"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
               android:text="B." />     
               <RadioButton
                   android:id="@+id/rb_C"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
               android:text="C." />     
               <RadioButton
                   android:id="@+id/rb_D"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
               android:text="D." />                                                                 

           </RadioGroup>
       </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Next" />

        </LinearLayout>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/summary"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_above="@+id/timer"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a ScrollView actually.

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your **TextView** in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
 yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

in your code.

And, It will scroll automatically without any issues.
Try out.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="user :" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSoalCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="hello_world"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtSoalCount"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="timer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Score" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/timer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/mainContent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSoal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dummy Tect" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgAnswer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_A"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="A." />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_B"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="B." />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_C"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="C." />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_D"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="D." />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a HorizontalScrollView?

See example at: http://androidsbs.blogspot.com/2013/11/scroll-text-with-finger-in-textview.html